# Header in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, header

How do I put the header in one line?

My problem is on [this page](http://app.liturgia.pt/menu12/011AdvHinos.html). I have a group of buttons in a script file but puts it in the header it moves to the bottom line.

My code looks like:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>HYMNS: Advent</h1>
    <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-right">
        <script language="JavaScript" src="botoes_comuns.js"></script>
    </a>
</div> <!-- /header -->
```

Comment: Are you able to give it another class?

Answer (score 0):

This is about the closest I could come without modifying your html structure.

First wrap your header content in `<center>` tags, and give the tags a class like `some_class`:

```
<center class="some_class"><h1 class="ui-title" tabindex="0" role="heading" aria-level="1">Advento</h1></center>
```

Then use the following css, alter as needed:

```css
center.some_class {
    margin: 5px 15% -28px 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: There is resulting. He will always create my group of buttons on a line below.
Is it because I have this group of buttons in a single file. Js?

Comment: @dmachado I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: The cause of the buttons to the right to pass a second line is due to file: <script language="JavaScript" src="botoes_comuns.js"> </ script>?

Comment: @dmachado .. I don't really see how this is relevant.  Does the css work or not?

Comment: the buttons on this page are right on header: http://app.liturgia.pt/menu12/012AdvDomI-III.html
but if I put a title since the buttons goes to another line and I did not. Would you like to stay titlo the center and the buttons to the right

Comment: Are you able to control where the header appears in relation to the other html elements?

Comment: yes. In the HTML i have:

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Advento</h1>
            <script language="JavaScript" src="botoes_comuns.js"></script>
        </div><!-- /header -->


an in CSS:
.ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title { min-height: 1.1em; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; /*display: block;*/ display: inline; margin: .6em 90px .8em;  padding: 0;  text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; outline: 0 !important; }

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are generating the button bar using js?  The code itself(the js) doesn't appear php generated.

Comment: I'm just using HTML and java script, so that was the only way I could insert the file with javascript

Comment: Thank you for your new code. works properly, but when I turn the iPhone changed the menu to the left.

Comment: I'll have to look at it tomorrow, it's way too late for me.

Comment: Now works. He had changed the display: block; Everything is working well. Thank you for your support needs.

Comment: If you like the answer, please click the checkbox under the vote-down arrow.